# Route my internal traffic through Raspberry Pi

Tags: routes, raspberry-pi, router

Here is my network structure

[image: Network]

When I am using any website or internet services the traffic goes through Raspberry Pi and I am able to see this.

But when I am accessing any services hosted by my mac from my phone, then it is going to be diverted by the router. I want to route my that traffic in following way:

Phone --> Router --> Raspberry Pi --> Router --> Mac

I tried setting up the proxy in my router but somehow it doesn't work. I have created a proxy server in Raspberry Pi using Squid Proxy.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to use services hosted on your MAC, you must have used the IP address of the MAC from the phone.

In such a case, the router knows that the communication is taking place in the local network, and will route the packets directly, without talking to the proxy server.

I have never tried doing this, but I believe your proxy system would work, if you disable the DHCP on your router, and use the raspberry pi as the DHCP server for the system.